# Amazon ECS Syslog to Loggly

Tags: amazon-web-services, syslog, amazon-ecs, loggly

I am using Loggly in my company to track nginx logs.

I've recently switched to Amazon ECS and I'm having difficulties configuring loggly for it.

In the amazon ECS interface, I configured loggly as following:
[image]

But according to the [loggly website](https://www.loggly.com/docs/streaming-syslog-without-using-files/), I need to add my customer token. But where do I do that? I tried in a seperate empty field but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? What configuration did you end up using? (minus your token of course). Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but Docker syslog driver does not support structured data. And Loggly specifically uses syslog structured data to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Karen from Loggly here. [Click here](https://www.loggly.com/docs/customer-token-authentication-token/?utm_source=link&utm_medium=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=42705&utm_content=answer) for documentation on finding your customer token.

Hope that helps! If you still have questions, feel free to [contact us](https://www.loggly.com/login/?next=/support&return_to=%2Fcustomer%2Fportal%2Femails%2Fnew) and we'll be happy to help everything get running smoothly for you!